# Column-wise select in browser

Tags: html, browser

Is there any HTML5 standard or CSS property which enforce the browser vendors to provide *column-wise* select for the content in the elements, especially in tables?

An advanced form of this behaviour is present in MS-Word for tables as well as the text: while holding Alt select the text, you can make a selection column-wise as well as row-wise.

Comment: No, but you could emulate that behaviour with JavaScript, if that's an option for you?

Comment: Yes JS is an option. Any idea where should I look for the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript for this. To accomplish this using jQUery, you just need to do something like:

```
$("tr").find("td:eq(2)")
```

This will select the all of the s in the third column.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly what you want but...

if you need to select the table cells with the mouse, e.g. for pasting them in excel,
you just need to press Ctrl and then drag to select any "square" section of a table, instead of the default behaviour of selecting rows from-to where you drag.

e.g.

```
A  B  C  D  E
1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14 15
```

if you just drag from lets say 3 to 14, you will select a partial first row `(3,4,5)`, a complete middle row `(6 through 10)` and a partial last row `(11 to 14)`

but if you hold Ctrl while dragging, you will select only COLUMNS, i.e. `3,4` , `8,9` and `13,14`

(it doesn't work here in SO, because it won't let us add html tables in a response) but you get the idea

It is pretty useful when you need to just grab a small portion of columns from a table.